# counting number of replacements done by gsub on an object of class Nokogiri::XML::Text

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, gsub

I was trying to replace a given pattern with some string in a object which is of class  Nokogiri::XML::Text using gsub in ruby..see the below command

```
#str is of class Nokogiri::XML::Text
str.content = str.content.gsub(pattern,replacing_word)
```

**Now I wanted to print something with each replacement and also wanted to know the number of replacement that gsub did so I wrote the below command**

```
count = 0
str.content = str.content.gsub(pattern,replacing_word) { count += 1
puts "some text"}
```

The above command is replacing the given pattern with the replacing_string but the body part of gsub is not getting executed, Neither any print statement nor any increment operation on count is happening.
Even I tried with just puts statement in the body then also it is not printing, although this gsub is doing many replacements in "str"

Let me know if anyone knows what is the issue with this gsub command

Answer (score 2):

try the following code snippet instead of yours,

```
content = content.gsub(pattern) {|m| count +=1; m.replace(replacing_word)}
```

My Testing Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
pattern = "a";
content = "abaccaa"
replacing_word = "z"
count = 0
content = content.gsub(pattern) {|m| count +=1; m.replace(replacing_word)}
puts content;
puts count;
```

Output

```
zbzcczz
4
```

--SJ

Comment: This solution doesn't actually reflect the change in content. The string matching the pattern in content is truncated after executing this command

Comment: can you give your sample content, pattern and replacing_word

Comment: I know it's super late but since i reached this, on rails 5 it worked as content = content.gsub(pattern) { |m| count +=1; replacing_word }